# 'Summary' tab in xcode not visible?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to change the launch image of my app using xcode but the 'summary' tab under the relevant target is not visible, I only see 'info', 'build settings', 'build phases' and 'build rules'.

Any ideas how I can get to the summary tab?

Comment: It appears that the "summary" tab no longer exists in XCode (v6.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the summary tab is not visible in some cases like when a project is yet to be built..

Answer (score 9):

Select the target, not the project.